Why does singular solution not satisfy the ode?
Should not singular solution also satisfy the ode itself? Since it is a solution.
Why does Mathematica V 14 in this example generate a singular solution which does not seem to satisfy the ode itself
ClearAll[y,x]
ode = y'[x] == y[x] + 3*y[x]^(1/3)
sol = DSolve[ode, y, x, IncludeSingularSolutions -> True]


The second singular solution above (one with complex I) does not satisfy the ode
ode/.sol[[2]]
(*True*)

ode /. sol[[3]]
(* False *)

Is this a bug or Am I overlooking something?
V 14 on windows 10

I don't think I can fully explain it but... It does warn that Inverse functions are being used by Solve, suggesting that some solutions may not be found (but not that some non-solutions may be found).  The constant solution (y'[x]==0) looks like a cubic equation, so naively we might expect 3 different constant solutions.  However, 3 y[x]^(1/3) + y[x] == 0 // Reduce gives only a single solution (as does Solve).  However, the solution is dependent on the branch cuts chosen for the cube root (which, is an area where Mathematica quite often does something unexpected).

If you replace y[x]^(1/3) with CubeRoot[y[x]], you get another weird solution:  Undefined! :)

This extended comment may help explain the situation.  The right side of ode has a branch cut on the negative real axis of y due to y^(1/3), which can be represented as a three-fold Reimann surface ( https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=39274091):

The transformation
ode3 = ode /. y -> Function[{x}, z[x]^3]

(* 3 z[x]^2 z'[x] == z[x]^3 + 3 (z[x]^3)^(1/3) *)

unwraps this structure into the complex plane.  ode3 has five solutions,
sz = DSolve[ode3, z, x, IncludeSingularSolutions -> True]

(* {{z -> Function[{x}, -Sqrt[-3 + E^((2 x)/3 + 2 C[1])]]}, 
    {z -> Function[{x}, Sqrt[-3 + E^((2 x)/3 + 2 C[1])]]}, 
    {z -> Function[{x}, 0]}, 
    {z -> Function[{x}, -I Sqrt[3]]}, 
    {z -> Function[{x}, I Sqrt[3]]}} *)

the second, fourth, and fifth of which correspond to the solutions to ode given in the question.  (Incidentally, solutions 5 and 4 are the limits of solutions 1 and 2 as x approaches -Infinity.)  The five solutions can be plotted with
ParametricPlot[{ReIm@(sz[[1, 1, 2, 2]] /. C[1] -> 0), 
    ReIm@(sz[[2, 1, 2, 2]] /. C[1] -> 0)}, {x, -5, 2.6}, 
    PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 1000, AxesLabel -> {Re[z], Im[z]}, 
    LabelStyle -> {12, Bold, Black}];
ListPlot[{{0, -Sqrt[3]}, {0, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}}, PlotStyle -> Red];
Plot[{ArcTan[2 Pi/3] x, -ArcTan[2 Pi/3] x}, {x, 0, Sqrt[3]}, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Dashed], Filling -> {1 -> {2}}];
Show[%%%, %%, %, PlotRange -> {{-Sqrt[3], Sqrt[3]}, {-Sqrt[3], Sqrt[3]}}]


The blue and orange curves correspond to the first and second solutions to ode3 above, and the three red points to the three singular, discrete solutions.
The superimposed shaded area maps into the space of y[s]^(1/3) as defined in Mathematica, with the dashed lines mapping into the branch cut.  Only the segment of the orange curve on the positive x real axis and the point x = 0 are in the shaded area and can be expected satisfy ode.  The former is that part of the second solution for which
Reduce[sz[[2, 1, 2, 2]] > 0, x, Reals]

(* x > 1/2 (-6 C[1] + 3 Log[3]) *)

Mapping back to y[x] yields
sy = {y -> Function[{x}, #]} & /@ (z[x]^3 /. sz)

(* {{y -> Function[{x}, -(-3 + E^((2 x)/3 + 2 C[1]))^(3/2)]}, 
    {y -> Function[{x}, (-3 + E^((2 x)/3 + 2 C[1]))^(3/2)]}, 
    {y -> Function[{x}, 0]}, 
    {y -> Function[{x}, 3 I Sqrt[3]]}, 
    {y -> Function[{x}, -3 I Sqrt[3]]}} *)

Backsubstituting these into ode with the constraint on x just discussed yields
FullSimplify[ode /. sy, -3 + E^((2 x)/3 + 2 C[1]) > 0]

(* {False, True, True, False, False} *)

(If, on the other hand, Mathematica had a function that captured the entirety of the fist plot and that function had been used in ode in place of y^(1/3), then all five solutions would have satisfied it.)  As mikado remarked in a comment above, DSolve has problems with branch cuts.  Why it chose to return just those three of the five possible solutions is unknown.  Even then, the second solution (orange curve) satisfies ode only for x > 1/2 (-6 C[1] + 3 Log[3]).
